# Firestore document field names with spaces return an error when used with .where() in Python

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Writing a really simple program in Python 3.7 using Firebase's Cloud Firestore. In the program I use .where() to pull down part of a collection and then iterate through it with a for loop. When any field name that has a space is passed into the .where() it throws an error (`google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid property path "Insert field name here"`) when it hits the loop.

I would think this should work, considering that I can both put data up and pull data down with these field names, just not use .where() with them. What am I doing wrong? Are spaces just not supported?

Here is a cut down version of the code I'm working with:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate(cert path)
applet = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

main_collection = db.collection(u'Referral_DB')
main_collection_obj = main_collection.where(u'English Name', u'==', u'Jerry').get()

for ref in main_collection_obj:
    pass
```

Comment: Have you tried `u'"English Name"'` ?

Comment: @JonClements Just did, throws the same error. '(^_^)

Comment: Okay... there must be some syntax that firebase will accept for escaping column names... maybe it's by putting it in `[]`s ?

Comment: @JonClements Tried that too and also a few other common ways to escape. The Firebase convention seems to be to generally avoid anything like that. The only exception I know of is when writing database rules for fields like this where you sub the space out for %20, which is unfortunately also interpreted literally here. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Short of not naming columns that way to start with... I've no idea - one would think it's possible *somehow* though if firebase doesn't explicitly disallow such column names...

Comment: Does the schema for that collection show names with spaces or has it transparently done some name mangling to replace/remove the space?

Comment: @JonClements In the Web interface the fields show exactly the names, with spaces (U+0020, I checked just in case XD). Pulling them down from the database using the field names with spaces also works.

Comment: Suppose the only other thing might be to use a raw string and put `\ ` to see if that works but  *shrugs*...

Comment: @JonClements Also tried that (\u0020) and also just escaping the space. Same error. Probably going to open a support ticket. Thanks for your help/time though!

Comment: If you do that and get a response (whether it's just a "don't have spaces in column names") - then make sure to post a self-answer... you've got me curious now :)

Comment: @JonClements Will do! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found in the limitations section of the documentation that the spaces need to be escaped by backticks.

This works:

```
main_collection_obj = main_collection.where(u'`English Name`', u'==', u'Jerry').get()
```

Answer (score 4):

According to our engineers, you should be using [`field_path`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/client.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.client.Client.field_path) to escape anything outside of ASCII letters, numbers, and underscores.

So your call would probably look something like

`main_collection.where(Client.field_path(u'English Name'), u'==', u'Jerry')`