# Python Firebase / Firestore update function fails with ValueError: Non-alphanum due to path not being consumed

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uuid

Updating via the Python Firestore API fails due to the update function splitting the string
resulting in an unescaped string that needs escaped

```
Traceback:
...
....
raise ValueError("Path {} not consumed, residue: {}".format(path, path[pos:]))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
....
ValueError: Non-alphanum char in element with leading alpha: e4dd7117-0d70-46bc-82a6-9a2de5a58c5e
```

This problem occurs when trying to add `uuid.uuid4()` to a firestore document via update. [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939273/start-getting-error-non-alphanum-char-in-element-with-leading-alpha-error-wh) suggests using `field_path but this adds additional backticks to the string and writes the data into the firestore document with those backticks included

1. How can `uuid4()` be updated in firestore without raising the following error
2. If there is no solution to (1) and `field_path` must be used, then how to avoid the additional backticks from being written out.

Thanks

Comment: Would you have code to show? Here reproduced the behaviour using `firestore_client.field_path` and getting backticks on the resulting UUID string (a string object, not a `uuid.uuid4()` object). Yet on update the field is the UUID string, without backticks.